# Definición de "pistear"

Tags: diferencias-regionales, modismos, méxico

Hoy alguien usó la palabra *pistear* conmigo, en el contexto de una fiesta, o bebiendo.  No puedo encontrar una definición relevante.  [DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/pistear) tiene dos definiciones regionales:

> 1. tr. *El Salv.* Pagar dinero a alguien a cambio de un favor o un servicio.
> 2. tr. *Hond.* Dicho de una persona: Ganar dinero. U. t. c. prnl.

Pero ninguna parece relevante a mi conversación aquí en México.

¿Qué significa *pistear* en ese contexto?  Y ¿donde se usa esa palabra así?

Comment: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pisto seems you're investing your time quite well :=)

Comment: pistear tomar alcohol , estar borracho , tomar cerveza , tequila

Comment: No es una respuesta 100% válida en el contexto (México), por eso la pongo como comentario.
en Colombia le conozco dos usos a _pistear_ (nunca he escuchado pisto):
- `Estaba pisteando a esa chica`
Significa que la estaba espiando en una situación indebida. Por ejemplo: mientras se cambiaba de ropa o iba al baño.
- `Pistee que no venga el profesor`
Significa estar alerta y avisar cuando el profesor se esté acercando.

Comment: Siempre es interesante ver la definición en el diccionario de americanismos: [_pistear_](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=A08yqlpZ5x0AJKTPcwR): _I. 1. tr. Mx. Ingerir bebidas alcohólicas. pop + cult → espon._. Luego tiene otros significados en El Salvador, Honduras y Cuba.

Comment: Coincido con @SergioVelásquez, en Colombia "pistear" se usa cuando se sigue a una persona, o se está en el proceso de averiguar algo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Significa beber.

Según el "Diccionario de México" de Juan Palomar de Miguel:

> **pistear.** intr. fam. *Méx.* Ingerir bebidas alcohólicas (NO). // fam. *Méx.* Dormir la siesta o echar un sueñito (Chih.).

Aunque es un modismo original del Norte de México, se ha adoptado en casi toda la república.

De igual manera, la segunda acepción de **pisto** aparece como "bebida":

> **pisto** m. fam. *Mex.* Trago de licor (NO).

Comment: Definitivamente se refiere al acto de ingerir bebidas alcohólicas. (México). Como dato curioso en una película que trata sobre Chico Mendes (Brasil, selva) se hace uso del verbo pistear al hacer referencia al acto de beber alcohol. Me parece que la pelìcula se llama "Temporada de Incendios" con Raul Julia.

Answer (score 4):

Probablemente relacionado con que, según el Diccionario de la lengua, [**alpiste**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=24j7EFV) es:

> 3. m. coloq. Bebida alcohólica.

y "**darle al alpiste**" se utiliza con el significado de "**beber algún tipo de bebida alcohólica**", por ejemplo [aquí](http://dzcdzc.blogspot.com.es/2007/07/darle-al-alpiste.html):

> **Darle al alpiste**: beber algún tipo de bebida alcohólica.

[aquí](http://www.poprosa.com/europa/confirmado-amy-winehouse-murio-por-accidente-tras-darle-al-alpiste)

> Confirmado: Amy Winehouse murió por accidente tras **darle al alpiste**. El caso está cerrado poproseros. Amy Winehouse murió accidentalmente tras una fuerte intoxicación alcohólica.

o [aquí](http://www.420radiocr.com/news/files/%E2%80%9Cpour-some-liquor%E2%80%9D-es-el-nuevostarvideo-de-los-jamaicanos-tok-con-jr-reid-y-maino.aspx)

> "...tradición legendaria en la isla, consistente en derramar un poco de licor en honor a algun amigo o familiar que ha fallecido. Es una manera de recuerdo y saludo especialmente si le gustaba **darle al alpiste**."

Answer (score 2):

En Guatemala **pistear** indica dar dinero o algo de valor a cambio de un favor.  Usualmente utilizado en forma peyorativa, ya que usualmente implica corrupción de algún tipo.  Básicamente, dinero bajo la mesa para conseguir algo, usualmente no completamente legal.

Comment: Buen aporte acerca del matiz peyorativo de la palabra en el contexto de pago por servicios.

Answer (score 2):

*Pistear* en Colombia no necesariamente está relacionado con algo ilegal.

Puede ser un sinonimo de "ver". Por ejemplo: "nos pisteamos" es un "nos vemos" a manera de despedida.

También como *cuidar* o *vigilar*. Por ejemplo "pistee el carro mientras descargamos" es un "cuide el carro mientras descargamos (productos o mercancias)".

Answer (score 0):

En México, **pistear** es tomar bebidas alcohólicas, independientemente del contexto, de forma que la expresión se usa tanto en entornos familiares como filiales, amistosos, románticos, etc.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).